# Update database based on jsp input

Tags: jsp, jdbc

i've a jsp as below.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form name="a" action="abc.jsp" method="post">
            <input type="abc" id="abc" name="abc">
            <input type="def" id="def" name="def"></form>
        </body>
    </html>

and the jsp that it is redirected is as below 

        <%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%try
            {
           int s;
        String a=request.getParameter("a");
        String b=request.getParameter("b");
        String c=request.getParameter("Ship_ID");
        ps=con.prepareStatement("select TSI_QUERY,TSI_R,TSI_C,SI_QUERY,SI_R, SI_C from topical");
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
        if(rs.getString("TSI_Query")==null && rs.getString("SI_Query")!=null)
        {
            String p="update topical set SI_Query='"+a+"', SI_R='x',SI_C='y' where Job_ID='"+c+"'";
            System.out.print(p);
            /*ps1=con.prepareStatement("update topical set TSI_Query=?, TSI_R=?,TSI_C=?");
            ps1.setString(1, a);
            ps1.setString(2, "x");
            ps1.setString(3, "y");
            s=ps1.executeUpdate();
            if(s!=0){
                String redirectURL= "a.jsp";
                response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
            }*/
        }
              else if(rs.getString("SI_Query")==null && rs.getString("TSI_Query")!=null)
        {
            String p="update topical set SI_Query='"+b+"', SI_R='x',SI_C='y'where Job_ID='"+c+"'";
            System.out.print(p);

            /*ps1=con.prepareStatement("update topical set SI_Query=?, SI_R=?,SI_C=?");
            ps1.setString(1, b);
            ps1.setString(2, "x");
            ps1.setString(3, "y");
            s=ps1.executeUpdate();
            if(s!=0){
            String redirectURL= "a.jsp";
            response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);}*/
        }
               else if(rs.getString("SI_Query")==null && rs.getString("TSI_Query")==null){
                   if(a==null && b!=null)
                                             {
                 String p="update topical set TSI_Query='"+a+"', TSI_R='x',TSI_C='y'where Job_ID='"+c+"'";
            /* ps1=con.prepareStatement("update topical set TSI_Query=?, TSI_R=?,TSI_C=?");
            ps1.setString(1, a);
            ps1.setString(2, "x");
            ps1.setString(3, "y");
            s=ps1.executeUpdate();
             if(s!=0){
                String redirectURL= "a.jsp";
                response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
                               }
              */     }
                 else if(b==null && a!=null){
            String p="update topical set SI_Query='"+b+"', SI_R='x',SI_C='y'where Job_ID='"+c+"'";
            System.out.print(p);
                     /*
            ps1=con.prepareStatement("update topical set SI_Query=?, SI_R=?,SI_C=?");
            ps1.setString(1, b);
            ps1.setString(2, "x");
            ps1.setString(3, "y");
            s=ps1.executeUpdate();
            if(s!=0){
                String redirectURL= "a.jsp";
                response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
                               }*/
                 }
               }
               }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        out.println(e);
        }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

here i want to update my database table with non null values received and the other column should not be updated as null as this column might be update some another time. but, it is displaying a blank page, not any query string, please let me know how do i get that query string displayed.

Thanks

Comment: Read Faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq on how to ask questions and come back with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I try to understand your code, you seem to be having three cases

Case 1

```
TSI_Query == null && SI_Query != null
//print something
```

Case 2

```
SI_Query ==null && TSI_Query != null
//print something
```

Case 3

```
SI_Query ==null && TSI_Query == null
  // check values of a and b, and print only if b==null && a!=null
```

So you have effectively, *NOT* followed all possible paths! It is no wonder that you don't have any output. Mind you, you could be other problems too.

Comment: What is that you did not get?

Comment: "NOT followed all possible paths!"